# How to get this JavaScript burger menu to work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

I’m following a tutorial online trying to jazz up my nav bars slightly and cannot get my burger menu and the animations to work.

I have linked the JS file above `</body>` (also tried moving it into the `<head>`).

Could it be to do with the way it is saved or have I made a very obvious mistake?

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
  
  //Toggle Nav //
  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
  });
}

navSlide();
```

```css
.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%;
}

.nav-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: #006a71;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 30%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%) !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="burger">
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
  <div class="line3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem? [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) Is it the missing `.nav-links.nav-active li{ opacity: 1; }` rule?

Comment: Sorry wasn't clear, the animations aren't working. The burger shows on screen when scaled to mobile but then the menu doesn't appear on clicking the menu

Answer (score 0):

It is you are added burger menu line to white background so it doesn't show.

change the color to black.

```
.burger div {
    background-color: black;
}
```

and change opacity of

```
.nav-links.nav-active li{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

and also change color of (because in desktop view nothing shows)

```
.nav-links a {
  color: #111;
}
```

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
  
  //Toggle Nav //
  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
  });
}

navSlide();
```

```css
.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%;
}

.nav-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #111;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px;
}
.nav-links.nav-active li{
  opacity: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: #006a71;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 30%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%) !important;
}

.nav-links a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: black;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="burger">
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
  <div class="line3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to detect the problem. basically the JS file didn't need to be surrounded by a function. I simplified it so that the variables and the toggle function were separated. With the opacity issue I changed the z index to make it appear 'infront' of the other elements